# Regex to validate custom format

Tags: java, regex

I have this format: `xx:xx:xx` or `xx:xx:xx-y`, where x can be 0-9 a-f A-F and y can be only 0 or 1.

I come up with this regex: `([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:][0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:][0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[-][0-1]{1})`

(See [regexr](http://regexr.com/4rfv9)).

But this matches `0a:0b:0c-3` too, which is not expected.

Is there any way to remove these cases from result?

Comment: Change `[0-1]` to `[01]`.

Comment: `[:]` means a character from the list that contains only `:`. It is the same as `:`. The same for `[-]` which has the same result as `-`.

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

`xx:xx:xx` or if it is followed by a `-`, then it must be a `0` or `1` and then it is the end (word boundry).

So you don't want any of these

```
0a:0b:0c-123
0a:0b:0cd
10a:0b:0c
```

either.

Then you want "negative lookingahead", so if you match the first part, you don't want it to be followed by a `-` (the first pattern) and it should end there (word boundary), and if it is followed by a `-`, then it must be a `0` or `1`, and then a word boundary:

```
/\b([0-9a-f]{2}[:][0-9a-f]{2}[:][0-9a-f]{2}(?!-)\b|\b[0-9a-f]{2}[:][0-9a-f]{2}[:][0-9a-f]{2}-[01]\b)/i
```

To prevent any digit in front, a word boundary is added to the front as well.

Example: https://regexr.com/4rg42

The following almost worked:

```
/\b([0-9a-f]{2}[:][0-9a-f]{2}[:][0-9a-f]{2}\b[^-]|\b[0-9a-f]{2}[:][0-9a-f]{2}[:][0-9a-f]{2}-[01]\b)/i
```

but if it is the end of file and it is `3a:2b:11`, then the `[^-]` will try to match a non `-` character and it won't match.

Example: https://regexr.com/4rg4q

Comment: brilliant @nopole what I am missing is the negative lookingahead I think, works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

`[:]` means a character from the list that contains only `:`. It is the same as 
`:`. The same for `[-]` which has the same result as `-`.
Also, `{1}` means "the previous piece exactly one time". It does not have any effect, you can remove it altogether.

To match `xx:xx:xx` or `xx:xx:xx-y`, the part that matches `-y` must be optional. The quantifier `?` after the optional part mark it as optional.

All in all, your `regex` should be like this:

```
[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}(-[01])?
```

If the `regex` engine you use can be told to ignore the character case then you can get rid of `A-F` (or `a-f`) from all character classes and the `regex` becomes:

```
[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}(-[01])?
```

How it works, piece by piece:

```
[0-9a-f]      # any digit or letter from (and including) 'a' to 'f'
{2}           # the previous piece exactly 2 times
:             # the character ':'
[0-9a-f]
{2}
:
[0-9a-f]
{2}
(             # start a group; it does not match anything
  -           # the character '-'
  [01]        # any character from the class (i.e. '0' or '1')
)             # end of group; the group is needed for the next quantifier
?             # the previous piece (i.e. the group) is optional
              # it can appear zero or one times
```

See it in action: https://regexr.com/4rfvr

#### Update

As @the-fourth-bird mentions in a comment, if the `regex` must match the entire string then you need to anchor its ends:

```
^[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}(-[01])?$
```

`^` as the first character of a `regex` matches the beginning of the string, `$` as the last character matches the end of the string. This way the `regex` matches the entire string only (when there aren't other characters before or after the `xx:xx:xx` or `xx:xx:xx-y` part).

If you use the `regex` to find `xx:xx:xx` or `xx:xx:xx-y` in a larger string then you don't need to add `^` and `$`. Of course, you can add only `^` or `$` to let the `regex` match only at the beginning or at the end of the string.

Comment: Not sure what the OP wants, but if the string should not match at all instead of a partial match, you might also add anchors `^$`. +1

Comment: @axiac kudos to detailed explanation, but the suggested regex still match the unexpected string. nopole's suggestion works in my case